# How to cover the entire page width, regardless what the screen size user have with a fixed manu?

Tags: css, css-float

I have a problem with a menu that is fixed and centered on the page. I want the entire menu (3 background images) to cover the entire page width, regardless what the screen size user have.

Orginal pictures:

(Picture 1: width **1px**, height 76px;)
(Picture 2: width 1135px, height 76px;)
(Picture 3: width **1px**, height 76px;)

After CSS changes I want those to become:

(Picture 1: width **392,5px**, height 76px;)
(Picture 2: width 1135px,  height 76px;)
(Picture 3: width **392,5px**, height 76px;)

```
<div style="position:fixed; width:100%; height:76px;">
  <div> Picture 1 </div>  <!-- repeat-x on the left side -->
  <div> Picture 2 , center of the page , no-repeat</div>
  <div> Picture 3</div>  <!--  repeat-x on the right side -->
</div>
```

I want to set the repeat-x on picture 1 and 3, but don't know the width. I can fix it with jQuery but aren't there a way in CSS?

Comment: i'd suggest you post an image of the result that you want, will be lots easier to answer

Comment: What do you mean "after CSS changes"? Are you expecting a click, a hover, etc.?

Comment: Nope. I wan't "repeat-x" to fill the width of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated for transparent center image** See, http://jsfiddle.net/QEPX4/5/show/

HTML

```
<div class="TriHeader">
  <div class="left"><div></div></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS (representative)

```
.TriHeader {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:76px;
}

.TriHeader div {
    height: 76px;
    position: absolute;
}

.TriHeader .left {
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
    z-index: 0;
}

.TriHeader .left div {
    background: url(repeatingLeftImage.png) top left repeat-x;
    right: 567.5px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.TriHeader .center {
    background: url(nonrepeatingCenterImage.png) top left no-repeat;
    width: 1135px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -567.5px; /*ideally, the image would be an even number */
    z-index: 1;
}

.TriHeader .right {
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

.TriHeader .right div {
    background: url(repeatingRightImage.png) top left repeat-x;
    left: 567.5px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

If you don't care about IE7, then you can eliminate the nested `div` elements in the left and right sides and replace the css with pseudo element selectors like:

```
.TriHeader .right:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(repeatingRightImage.png) top left repeat-x;
    left: 567.5px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the picture in the middle have transparent. This was close to a solution..

Comment: @Plexus81--I've updated to allow for a transparent center image.

Comment: Thanks! It works :) Think it's strange that CSS don't support this out of the box, like repeat-x right/left.